# ios - html form trying to go to next page when submitted - how to stop it?

Tags: ios, ios5

I am using an HTML view to display a form. It works, but the only problem is that the form tries to go to the next page when it submits, and I do not want that to happen. How can I prevent this form from trying to go to the next page?

```
    <div id="stylized" class="myform">
        <form id="form" class="myform" method="post"
            action="http://www.mydomain.com/my_page.php?platform=ios" >
            <label>Your Name:</label>
                <input name="name" id="name" />

            <label>Your Email:</label> <input name="email" id="email" />

            <button type="submit" value="Submit" />Submit</button>
            <div class="spacer"></div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Here is the controller for it. I wrote it some time ago and now actually do not even completely understand where/how the remote call is made to send this info to the server:

```
@interface PremiumController ()

@end

@implementation PremiumController
@synthesize theWebView;



- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)aWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{   
    if ([request.URL.scheme isEqualToString:@"http"]) 
    {
stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"escape(document.getElementById(\"phone\").value);"];

        [theWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"alert(\"Information sent successfully. Simply ensure that what you had entered was correct.\");"];
    }  

    return YES;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    theWebView.delegate = self;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setTheWebView:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{  
    NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"premium" ofType:@"html"];    
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:htmlFile];
    NSURLRequest *rq = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [theWebView loadRequest:rq];

    // EMAIL
    NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSString *user_id = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"user_id"]; 
    NSString *user_email = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"email"]; 

    EmailUtil *email_obj = [[EmailUtil alloc] initWithSubject:@"iPremium Loaded" body:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"User id: %@ and email: %@" , user_id , user_email ]];

    [email_obj send]; 
    // END EMAIL
}

@end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you lookup to [UIWebViewDelegate Protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIWebViewDelegate) the first delegate method `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` is you need to return a `BOOL`.

> **Return Value** YES if the web view should begin loading content;
>   otherwise, NO.

this means if you return YES the webView will continue to load the request, if NO then the webView will not load the request. Hope this will help.